# Do rate-of-fire modifiers affect the Blasphemy sword in Enter the Gungeon?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

I was playing Enter the Gungeon using the Blasphemy sword, and I picked up the Lichy Trigger Finger passive, which increases the rate of fire for all weapons. However, it seemed like the rate at which I could swing the sword hadn't increased at all. So, is Blasphemy an exception, or am I just imagining it?

Comment: I recently experienced the same thing, and felt the item had no effect on Blasphemy. I thought it might be because the time between attacks is technically reloading, but the [wiki page](http://enterthegungeon.gamepedia.com/Blasphemy) shows a 0.2 second rate of fire time and 1 second reload time, neither of which seem to match up with the weapon's effective rate of fire.

Comment: The "reload" for Blasphemy is the mini-blank triggered by double-tapping reload while at full health. As for the fire rate, a value of 0.2 would imply 5 shots per second (i.e. 0.2 seconds per shot) , while the actual fire rate of Blasphemy is more like twice per second. Based on this, my guess is that the swing animation always takes a fixed amount of time (about 1/3 second), while the "fire rate" is the delay between the end of one swing and the beginning of the next. If this is the case, then items that increase fire rate would only shorten the 0.2 seconds, not the 1/3-second swing.